# Help with part identification

Tags: identification

Can someone tell me what this part is?  I think it is a diode.   The markings say 0830 1Z. It is from an 18v lithium power tool battery.  Reading the 5 - 18650 cells shows 3.99v per cell and 19.95v for the pack but going through the BMS is only showing 7.4 ish volts. It is definitely damaged. I don't know if simply replacing this part will solve the problem or if there is another fault that will blow out the new part but it's worth a try.

[image: What is this part?]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: "It is definitely damaged." Reading that and then looking at that second picture gave me a good chuckle.

Comment: Definitly a diode, good chance of it being a TVS. Can you post a photo of it with a bit more PCB in view? Can you see if the power path is in series with this diode or parallel?

Comment: Welcome! Please trace out the circuit around and connected to it.

Comment: Best guess: 30 V Zener diode straight across the rail.  Unsolder it and measure if the MOSFET next to it is ok with you DMM diode function.

Answer (score 1):

Browsing a lot of online chinese datasheets I've come with this [one PDF](https://www.datasheetarchive.com/pdf/download.php?id=370d283ee3b4e374f2ddb21b9469d1c2c29434&type=P&term=Zener%2520diode%2520marking%2520NZ) that looks promising.

It says that it is a **200mW SOD-323 SURFACE MOUNT Small Outline Flat Lead Plastic Package Zener Voltage Regulator**. They are available from 2.4V to 75V, depending on the marking. The `1Z` states that this is a **2.7V** one.

Note that the IZ, OZ and QZ are missing from the table, to avoid confusions with the identification.

The `0830` is maybe the date of manufacture (year 2008, week 30?).

Answer (score 0):

The significant marking is "IZ", in the second picture we can see that it is a "I" and not a "1".

The package is SMA (standard size + J lead shape).
With that marking code, one can find that it is a SMAJ24A diode.
This is a generic part number, a lot of manufacturers make these parts.

After a search in google I eventually found that the manufacturer of your model is LGE. (No marking in the [datasheet](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1004749/LGE/SMAJ24A/1) unfortunately)

But in the following picture from [LCSC](https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/Lge-SMAJ24A/C320534) you can see that the marking is similar to yours:

[image]

By the way someone looked for the same diode [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/439301/please-help-to-identify-smd-diode), and didn't find it either.